# react-quill: [Parchment] Unable to create [object HTMLDivElement] blot in react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ckeditor, react-quill

Here is my code,i used react-quill pluggin

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactQuill from "react-quill";


class Editor extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      text: ""
    };
  }

  modules = {
    // #3 Add "image" to the toolbar
    toolbar: [["bold", "italic"]]
  
  };

  formats = [
    "header",
    "bold",
    "italic",
    "underline",
    "strike",
    "blockquote",
    "list",
    "bullet",
    "indent",
    "link"
  ];

  render() {
    return (
      <ReactQuill
        theme="snow"
        modules={this.modules}
        formats={this.formats}
        value={this.state.text}
      >
        <div className="my-editing-area" />
      </ReactQuill>
    );
  }
}

export default Editor;
```

same code working on my another project and its versions mentioned in here unable to find the issue. even i am not used image option in quill editor.

react 16.6.0
react-dom 16.6.0
react-quill 1.3.1
react-scripts 2.0.3

Comment: Sir, your code is working [Live Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-69903804-ospy2)

Comment: but, it shows this issue while integrating in existing application